# mdl-textfield not taking ngModel changes into account

Tags: angularjs, material-design-lite

I am facing an issue regarding the `mdl-textfield`'s behavior

On the below plnkr, follow the steps:

1. click on "groups working"
2. click on "copy" on one item
3. look at the very end new textfield appeared with the ngModel associated (angular.copy) but the behavior of the textfield is strange, even if there is a value, the label is not floating but if you click in the textfield, it floats as expected. If you modify the field the behavior remains, but if you quit it without any modification label comes back with overlay.

http://plnkr.co/edit/MUI2iBslIH9jd4fgEQPL?p=preview

`ngView` content

```
<div data-ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <section data-ng-repeat="fo in foo">
    <div class="mdl-textfield mdl-js-textfield mdl-textfield--floating-label">
      <input class="mdl-textfield__input" type="text" id="sample1" data-ng-model="fo.bar"/>
      <label class="mdl-textfield__label" for="sample1">{{fo.bar}}</label>
      <span ng-if="$last" ng-init="update()"></span>
    </div>
    <button ng-click="focopy(fo)">Copy</button>
  </section>
    <div data-ng-show="datacopy.edit" class="input-field">
      <input type="text" id="ex1" data-ng-model="datacopy.bar" />
      <label for="ex1">label</label>
    </div>
</div>
```

Angular module

```
var app=angular.module('plunker', ['ngRoute'])
app.config(function($routeProvider){
    $routeProvider
    //Root URL
    .when('/',{template:'<p>Coucou</p>'})
    .when('/groups',{templateUrl:'groups.html'})
    .when('/groupsnotworking',{templateUrl:'groupsnotworking.html'})
});

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope,$timeout) {
$scope.foo = [
  {bar: 'world'},{bar:'toto'},{bar:'toto'}
];
$scope.groups=$timeout(function(){
  $scope.groups=$scope.foo
},1000);
$scope.update=function(){
  componentHandler.upgradeAllRegistered();
};
$scope.datacopy={};
$scope.focopy=function(data){
  $scope.datacopy=angular.copy(data);
  $scope.datacopy.edit=true;
};
});
```

Hope it is clear enough.
I tried to post that on the github of material design lite thinking it was a bug, but I have been kicked off here...
Thank you

Comment: Have you done everything MDL says for use with dynamic sites? You have to let it know to compile elements added later: http://www.getmdl.io/started/#dynamic

Comment: Yes, on the plnker you can see the update button lauching the function 'componentHandler.upgradeAllRegistered()'. Anyway, the behavior of the textfield is ok if you consider the floating label and the underline animation.

Comment: I tested with Materialize, same kind of behavior (less buggy as the normal behavior is coming as soon as the control gets the focus)

Answer (score 3):

When you an `mdl-textfield__input`'s `ng-model`value is set after the mdl component is registered, the `mdl-textfield` does not get the `is-dirty` class, thus does not behave the way it should.

You can use this directive on your `mdl-textfield__input field :

```
"use strict";
(function(){
  let mdlTfFix = () => {
    return {
      restrict: "C",
      require: "ngModel",
      link: ($scope, $element, $attrs, ngModelCtrl) => {
        $scope.$watch(() => {
          return ngModelCtrl.$modelValue;
        }, (newVal, oldVal) =>{

          if(typeof newVal !== "undefined" && newVal !== "" && newVal !== oldVal){
            $element.parent().addClass("is-dirty");
          }
          else{
            $element.parent().removeClass("is-dirty");
          }
        });
      }
    };
  };

  mdlTfFix.$inject = [];
  app.directive("mdlTextfieldInput", mdlTfFix);

})();
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to manually clean up MDL js text inputs if cleared via scripting.  After clearing input value, for example, call this `mdlCleanup();`.

```
  //MDL Text Input Cleanup
  function mdlCleanUp(){
    var mdlInputs = doc.querySelectorAll('.mdl-js-textfield');
    for (var i = 0, l = mdlInputs.length; i < l; i++) {
      mdlInputs[i].MaterialTextfield.checkDirty();
    }  
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

working with me. hope this can help you

```
function CleanMDL() {
        setTimeout(function () {
            $scope.$apply(function () {
                var x = document.getElementsByClassName("mdl-js-textfield");
                var i;
                for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
                    x[i].MaterialTextfield.checkDirty();
                }
            })
        }, 100);
    }
```