# Material Design Lite form won't render after asynchronous filling

Tags: forms, asynchronous, data-binding, material-design

I have a form, rendered with Material Design Lite, which I populate thanks to a callback of an asynchrnous REST Api call but I am getting the following result in my DOM:

[image]

If I focus on a textfield, it shows normally, because not if I don't (the title must be over the text). When I look into the HTML, I see the `value` attribute doesn't show and that's propbably why. I populate the fields this way:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/api/v1/map/config',
    method: 'get',
    success: function(response) {
        this.xoffset = response.xoffset;
        this.yoffset = response.yoffset;
        this.xscaling = response.xscaling;
        this.yscaling = response.yscaling;
        this.path = response.path;

        $("input[name=xoffset]").val(response.xoffset);
        $("input[name=yoffset]").val(response.yoffset);
        $("input[name=xscaling]").val(response.xscaling);
        $("input[name=yscaling]").val(response.yscaling);
        $(".map-preview").html("<img src='" + response.path + "' />");
        componentHandler.upgradeAllRegistered();
    },
    error: function(err) {
        err = JSON.parse(err.responseText);
        if (err.error) {
            SnackbarManager.pushError(err.error);
        } else {
            SnackbarManager.pushError("Une erreur s'est produite");
        }
    }
});
```

Thank you for your help

Comment: Try this answer : 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31638890/mdl-textfield-not-taking-ngmodel-changes-into-account/40781433#40781433

Answer (score 1):

try this code... in my app, i had a problem with fields dynamical, after put in the html..

```
angular.module('app', ['ngRoute']).

run(function($rootScope, xxxx, xxx){
    $rootScope.$on('$viewContentLoaded', function(event, next) {
        componentHandler.upgradeAllRegistered();
    });
});
```