# Material Design Lite input floating label not working after page navigation

Tags: angularjs, html, css, material-design-lite

I currently building a mobile hybrid application using Material Design Lite but I've encountered a slight issue. When I'm adding input field elements to my pages, the floating text or even the placeholder does not work correctly.

I'm using `$stateProvider and $urlRouterProvider` in my application for page navigation. Inside my `index.html` I have `<div ui-view></div>` in which I inject my views when my states change using `<a ui-sref="home">Home</a>` for example.

The problem I'm having is that if insert the following code into `index.html` outside of the `ui-view` of course:

```
  <div class="mdl-textfield mdl-js-textfield mdl-textfield--floating-label">
    <input class="mdl-textfield__input" type="text" id="sample3">
    <label class="mdl-textfield__label" for="sample3">Text...</label>
  </div>
```

The floating label works no problem. However, if I place the same code inside a view (external page that is later injected inside the `ui-view` element after page navigation occurs), the floating label does not work correctly. The label does not float up, and the text entered is unreadable.

There are no errors displayed in my console and I can't seem to figure out why it won't work. The JS files and CSS are loaded in correctly.

Hopefully someone can help me out with this.

Thanks everyone!

Comment: I found the answer here : http://stackoverflow.com/a/40781433/1491212

Answer (score 1):

You have to upgrade the elements using "componentHandler.upgradeElements()"

Comment: Thanks. I'll give this a try and let you know.

Comment: where do I exactly call this function?